# Unexpected "Box Model" width in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to feed some SQL Server reports through an iframe on a web page. They display fine in IE (surprise!) but in Firefox and Chrome the report is terribly squashed widthways.

The HTML and Styles used by these reports are buried on the SQL Server box and not easily editable. But using Firebug I was able to delve in to see where the problem was and fiddle with the styles to try and solve the problem.

To my surprise, the element responsible was a TD element without a width value. I tried adding a width value, but it had no effect on the page - it was just ignored.

When I checked the computed style, I found the issue: Firefox reports a "Box Model" with of 167 px, which is used in favour of the width I specified.

While I understand the basics of the box model, I'm very confused as to how the browser has come up with this width. There's nothing I can find on the page at all that has a width specified to 167px. How's in been calculated, and how can I change it?

Comment: Unless you use `table-layout:fixed` on a table, the routines that work out what widths to use for the cells are very complicated. They take all kinds of things into account to fit as much info as possible in as small a space as they can get, while refraining from using scrollbars if possible. And yes, then a user-asigned `width` may not have much priority.

Comment: Thanks. Oddly, table-layout *is* set to fixed. Which would seem to make the issue yet more confusing :(

Comment: Removing table-layout: fixed actually seems to fix the problem. No idea why. O_o

Comment: Oh, OK. Ehm, you're welcome... You know, I think that table-layout may only work as advertised when you set _all_ column widths explicitly. If some are set and some aren't, maybe the browser will get confused. Otherwise I wouldn't know.